# Trying to fully understand JavaScript hoisting

Tags: javascript, hoisting

**Edit**
Looks like it was an issue on my part and my usage of jsfiddle :?

Ive been reading a couple of articles on hoisting lately, one is [by Nicholas Zakas](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/01/26/answering-baranovskiys-javascript-quiz/), and the other is [by Ben Cherry](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting).

Im trying to follow the examples and just test on my own to make sure I fully grasp it but Im having an issue mainly with this example,

```
if (!('a' in window)) {
    var a = 1;
}
console.log(a);
```

Instead of logging `undefined` its logging `1`. If I am understanding everything correctly, `a` should be `undefined`, because it *should* exist in the window scope due to the var statement being hoisted to the top, so it should not be assigned the value.

But the following is acting as expected,

```
(function bar(){
    console.log(foo);
    var foo = 10;  
    console.log(baz);
})();
```

`foo` is `undefined`, and `baz` is not defined. I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/VjCqF/2/) here with both examples. Really just trying to wrap my head around this. Has something changed since these articles were written maybe? If anyone can shed some light on this it would be appreciated. Im using Chrome 14 when testing.

Comment: I'm running your fiddle in Google Chrome and it prints `undefined`. For a good explanation of hoisting you can take a look at *O'Reilly JavaScript Patterns*.
There's a dedicated **paragraph**.

Comment: Yeah, apparently it was due to me not using jsfiddle correctly doh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the `wrap` in the fiddle to `no wrap(head)`

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/VjCqF/3/

Answer (score 2):

In the second example, hoisting transforms the code into this:

```
(function bar(){
    var foo;
    console.log(foo);
    foo = 10;  
    console.log(baz);
})();
```

So foo is undefined during the first call to log.  The declaration is always hoisted to the top of the enclosing function, but assignment is never hoisted with it.

Answer (score 2):

You have JSFiddle set to `onLoad`, so `var a` is scoped to the onLoad function. Change it to `no wrap` and you get:

```
undefined
undefined
Uncaught ReferenceError: baz is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

`object.a === undefined; // true`, but `a in object; // true`

```
var object = {a: undefined};

('a' in object); // is true because a is a property of object
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoisting is understood differently but to my understanding what it does is

Whenever you create an variable/functions it sets up a memory space for you.It does not put the variable/functions on the top of execution context.

Type 'this/window' in console you'll find your var/functions sitting there lexically.

for example:

```
a; //returns undefined 
b(); //returns Hello World   
var a = "Hello";
    function b() {
        console.log('Hello World');
    }
```

If it is placed on top during execution then it should output 'Hello' not    'undefined' functions will get excuted.Variables won't get excuted.
Please avoid hoisting excute the vars after it is being declared:

```
var a = "Hello";
    function b() {
        console.log('Hello World');
    }
a; //returns Hello

b(); //returns Hello World
```